# Unable to add Push Certificates for the second app on the same Firebase project

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I’ve started the Firebase Cloud Messaging implementation for two iOS applications, Client and Hairdresser app.

In Xcode terms I have one project with two targets, one for Client and another for Hairdresser app, each of them has two different Bundle ID’s.
For iOS dev console I have also to App Id’s for each Bundle ID with Push Notifications enabled. For each app I’ve exported the certificates as .p12 files.

I have a firebase project created, there I’ve added two iOS application, Hairdresser app with hairdresser Bundle ID, and another one for Client app with client Bundle ID

The problem:

- Let’s say that I’ve created the Hairdresser App first, and I’ve added the Hairdresser p.12 file, all is working fine and the certificate is accepted. If I will create the Client app after Hairdresser app, and will try to add the Client .p12 certificate I will receive the error: “The group ID specified in the certificate does not match the group ID you entered.” 
  If I will delete both apps and now I will create the client app and after this the hairdresser app, now adding the .p12 certificate for hairdresser will be impossible.

Additional question:

- In the same Xcode project I have two apps (two targets). Can I add the Firebase Cloud Messaging config files in separated folders (not root), one .plist file for one application(target). Will this work? If no, how can I indicate for each target what Configuration file to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I was able to setup the second app too. iOS guide for Firebase integration says that we need to export the private key as .P12 file from the Push Certificate in Keychain. This is working fine for first added app but not for the second. I’ve tried another methods to generate the .P12 file. Exporting directly the Apple Push Certificates from Keychain (not the private key) give the certificate that is accepted by the Firebase console. I don’t understand why the guide method doesn’t work … but at lest you will know about this.

Also we can add the Firebase Cloud Messaging config files in separated folders (not root), one .plist file for one application(target) and the second one for the second app.

Comment: @Adiran Zghibarta How did you do this? I mean I am facing the same issue, Do I need to generate two different app ids? Or If it is not then how will I set up two apps on firebase with one app id?

Comment: @AnuragSharma actually I have one Xcode project with two different targets. Each target has different app id, plist files etc. But on the iOS dev console I have two different apps. When you add the plist files with Firebase configuration you can chose the right target with the right app id.

Comment: @AdrianZghibarta looks sensible in your case, Now I have uploaded two .p12 files for both of my iOS apps in firebase. Notifications are working now!